# Prevent resteasy from accepting empty request body

Tags: java, resteasy

My resteasy app has a POST method, which accepts a Person in body and adds it to database. I'd expect that if client passed an invalid json (missing fields, or even an empty one!) the method wouldn't even start but I get 200 OK! How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: What version of RESTEasy are you using? Also, are you running in a container like WildFly?

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins RESTEasy version 3.15.3.Final and I'm running on Tomcat 8.5

Comment: I'm getting an exception with invalid JSON. You don't by some change have a reproducer do you? One option though would be a `ContainerRequestFilter` and examine the entity.

Comment: @JamesR.Perkins what does your Person class look like then? Mine has fields with jaxb annotations and they all have required = true

Comment: I just created a very basic one with no annotations. You must be using Jackson though if you're using JAXB annotations. I only tested with the Jakarta JSON Binding provider.